# Prolog: combined predicate failed

Tags: prolog, predicate, clpfd

As a beginner, I am trying to solve a matrix problem, in which the solution is either the summation or the multiplication of the distinct digit in the matrix. For example,`[[14,_,_,_],[15,_,_,_],[28,_,1,_]]`. The predicate should generate the solution according to the matrix. However, I bumped into a problem that my combined predicate failed, but each of them succeeded independently.

I broke the problem down to summation and multiplication. Therefore, using clpfd library, and some predicates, for summation:

```
removeHead([Head|Tail],Tail).

get_head_element([],_).
get_head_element([Head|Rest],Head).

solve_sum(Row,RestRow):-
    get_head_element(Row, Goal),
    removeHead(Row,RestRow),
    RestRow ins 1..9,
    all_distinct(RestRow),
    sum(RestRow, #=, Goal).
```

For multiplication:

```
multiply(List,Result):-
    multiply(List,1,Result).

multiply([Element|RestList],PrevResult,Result):-
    NextResult #= PrevResult * Element,
    multiply(RestList,NextResult, Result).

multiply([], Result, Result).

solve_multiply(Row,RestRow):-
    get_head_element(Row, Goal),
    removeHead(Row,RestRow),
    RestRow ins 1..9,
    multiply(RestRow,Goal),
    all_distinct(RestRow).
```

Both `solve_sum` and `solve_multiply` works for a single row, but here I combine these two predicates to:

```
solve_row_sum_or_multiply([],_).

solve_row_sum_or_multiply([HeadRow|Matrix],Solution):-
maplist(all_distinct,Matrix),
get_head_element(HeadRow,Goal),
( Goal >= 25
-> solve_multiply(HeadRow,Solution),
   write(Solution)
; ( solve_sum(HeadRow,Solution),
    write(Solution)
    ; solve_multiply(HeadRow,Solution),
    write(Solution))
),solve_row_sum_or_multiply(Matrix,Solution).
```

When I use the `solve_row_sum_or_multiply([[14,_,_,_],[15,_,_,_],[28,_,_,_]],X)`, it will give me the possible combinations. However, when `solve_row_sum_or_multiply([[14,_,_,_],[15,_,_,_],[28,_,1,_]],X)`, it gave me false, but there's a solution possible there, such as `[[14,7,2,1],[15,3,7,5],[28,4,1,7]]`.

I am wondering what could be wrong. Any help is highly appreciated!

**EDIT**

The problem is inside the combined predicate, and it's better to write the predicate which the answer suggests instead of a nested if-then-else predicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's review this code.

**intro code**

```
:- use_module(library(clpfd)).

% ---
% Make sure you see all the information in a list printed at the 
% toplevel, i.e. tell the toplevel to not elide large lists (print
% them in full, don't use '...')
% ---

my_print :-
   Depth=100,
   Options=[quoted(true), portray(true), max_depth(Depth), attributes(portray)],
   set_prolog_flag(answer_write_options,Options),
   set_prolog_flag(debugger_write_options,Options).
   
:- my_print.
```

**multiply/2**

Recode the `multiply/2` predicate so that it can be read more easily. Add test code to make sure it actually does what we think it does:

```
% ---
% Set up constraint: all the elements in List, multiplied
% together, must yield Result. If the List is empty, the
% Result must be 1.
% ---

multiply(Factors,Product):-
    multiply_2(Factors,1,Product).

multiply_2([Factor|Factors],PartialProduct,Product):-
    PartialProduct2 #= PartialProduct * Factor,
    multiply_2(Factors,PartialProduct2,Product).

multiply_2([],Product,Product).

solve_multiply([Product|Factors]):-
    Factors ins 1..9,
    multiply(Factors,Product),
    all_distinct(Factors).
    
% ---
% Testing
% ---

:- begin_tests(multiply).

test(1) :- 
   multiply([X,Y,Z],6),
   [X,Y,Z] ins 1..9,
   X #=< Y, Y #=< Z, 
   bagof([X,Y,Z],label([X,Y,Z]),Bag),
   sort(Bag,BagS),
   assertion(BagS == [[1, 1, 6], [1, 2, 3]]).

test(2) :- 
   multiply([],Result),
   assertion(Result == 1).

test(3) :- 
   multiply([X,Y],3),
   [X,Y] ins 1..9,
   X #=< Y, 
   bagof([X,Y],label([X,Y]),Bag),
   sort(Bag,BagS),
   assertion(BagS == [[1,3]]).

test(4) :-
   solve_multiply([6,X,Y,Z]),
   bagof([X,Y,Z],label([X,Y,Z]),Bag),
   sort(Bag,BagS),
   assertion(BagS == [[1,2,3],[1,3,2],[2,1,3],[2,3,1],[3,1,2],[3,2,1]]).
   
test(5) :-
   solve_multiply([362880,F1,F2,F3,F4,F5,F6,F7,F8,F9]),
   F1 #=< F2,
   F2 #=< F3,
   F3 #=< F4,
   F4 #=< F5,
   F5 #=< F6,
   F6 #=< F7,
   F7 #=< F8,
   F8 #=< F9,
   bagof([F1,F2,F3,F4,F5,F6,F7,F8,F9],label([F1,F2,F3,F4,F5,F6,F7,F8,F9]),Bag),
   sort(Bag,BagS),
   assertion(BagS == [[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]]).

test(6,fail) :-
   solve_multiply([-1,X,Y,Z]).
   
:- end_tests(multiply).
```

**solve_sum/1**

For summation, after simplifying and re-coding to Prolog's "pattern matching" style instead of (for want of a better word) "Algol calling style" as is used in the original the question (which confused me greatly I have to say).

This looks ok too. Note that the predicate `solve_sum/1` is quite different-in-argument-style from `multiply/2` It is better - and easier on the reader (and oneself) - if one keeps the same calling conventions.

```
solve_sum([Sum|Terms]):-
    Terms ins 1..9,
    all_distinct(Terms),
    sum(Terms, #=, Sum).
    
% ---
% Testing
% ---

:- begin_tests(sum).

test(0) :- 
   solve_sum([0]).
   
test(1) :- 
   solve_sum([6,X,Y,Z]),
   X #=< Y, Y #=< Z, 
   bagof([X,Y,Z],label([X,Y,Z]),Bag),
   sort(Bag,BagS),
   assertion(BagS == [[1, 2, 3]]).

test(2) :- 
   solve_sum([9,X,Y,Z]),
   X #=< Y, Y #=< Z, 
   bagof([X,Y,Z],label([X,Y,Z]),Bag),
   sort(Bag,BagS),
   assertion(BagS == [[1,2,6],[1,3,5],[2,3,4]]).

test(3,fail) :- 
   solve_sum([1,_X,_Y,_Z]).
   
:- end_tests(sum).
```

**A printing predicate to get nice results**

Prolog makes it easy to construct arbitrary structures "on the fly", one just has to stipulate exactly how the structure shall look.

Our "solution" is:

- A list
- With each element of the list a "row" (standing for one of the expressions)
- And the row a term: `row(Result,Op,RowValues)` where `Result` is the left-hand-side of an equation, `Op` is one of `add` or `mult` and `RowValues` is a list with the values found for the values in the equation.

```
print_solution([]).

print_solution([Labeling|Labelings]) :-
   format("---~n"),
   print_rows_of_solution(Labeling),
   format("---~n"),
   print_solution(Labelings).

print_rows_of_solution([]).

print_rows_of_solution([row(Result,Op,RowValues)|Rows]) :-
   print_row(Result,RowValues,Op),
   print_rows_of_solution(Rows).

print_row(Result,[RowEntry|RowEntries],Op) :-
   format("~q = ~q",[Result,RowEntry]),
   print_row_2(RowEntries,Op).
   
print_row_2([RowEntry|RowEntries],Op) :-
   ((Op == mult) -> OpChar = '*'
   ; (Op == add)  -> OpChar = '+'
   ; OpChar = '?'),
   format(" ~q ~q",[OpChar,RowEntry]),
   print_row_2(RowEntries,Op).
   
print_row_2([],_) :-
   format("~n").
```

**solve_row_sum_or_multiply/2**

This has been modified to also collect the operation selected in a second argument (a list).

Note that the "maplist-all-distinct over the matrix" is *not* done here because that seems wrong.

```
solve_row_sum_or_multiply([],[]).

solve_row_sum_or_multiply([Row|MoreRows],[mult|Ops]) :-
   Row = [X|_Xs],
   X >= 25,   
   solve_multiply(Row), % we now have imposed a product constraint on the current Row
   solve_row_sum_or_multiply(MoreRows,Ops).

solve_row_sum_or_multiply([Row|MoreRows],[add|Ops]) :-
   Row = [X|_Xs],
   X < 25,
   solve_sum(Row), % we now have imposed a sum constraint on the current Row
   solve_row_sum_or_multiply(MoreRows,Ops).
 
solve_row_sum_or_multiply([Row|MoreRows],[mult|Ops]) :-
   Row = [X|_Xs],
   X < 25,
   solve_multiply(Row), % alternatively, we now have imposed a product constraint on the current Row   
   solve_row_sum_or_multiply(MoreRows,Ops).
```

**And finally a "main" predicate**

In `trial_run/1` we stipulate that all variables except `X32` be distinct and that `X32` be 1. If `X32` were in the "distinct set", none of the variables could take on the value 1 - there is no solution in that case.

We also impose a sorting to get only a set of "canonical" solutions:

We collect all possible solutions for solving and labeling using `bagof/3`:

```
trial_run(Solutions) :-
   all_distinct([X11,X12,X13,X21,X22,X23,X31,X33]),
   X32=1,
   X11 #=< X12, X12 #=< X13,
   X21 #=< X22, X22 #=< X23,
   X31 #=< X33,
   % multiple solutions solving x labeling may exist; collect them all
   bagof(
      [
         row(14,Op1,[X11,X12,X13]),
         row(15,Op2,[X21,X22,X23]),
         row(28,Op3,[X31,X32,X33])
      ],
      (
         solve_row_sum_or_multiply( [[14,X11,X12,X13],[15,X21,X22,X23],[28,X31,X32,X33]], [Op1,Op2,Op3] ),
         label([X11,X12,X13,X21,X22,X23,X31,X32,X33])
      ),   
      Solutions).
```

**Does it work?**

Apparently yes, and there is only one solution:

```
?- trial_run(Solutions),print_solution(Solutions).
---
14 = 2 + 3 + 9
15 = 1 + 6 + 8
28 = 4 * 1 * 7
---
Solutions = [[row(14,add,[2,3,9]),row(15,add,[1,6,8]),row(28,mult,[4,1,7])]].
```

Comment: Thanks, the multiply predicate works, but the combined predicate is not working as expected. I think something wrong with the logic inside the combined one, but have no idea.

Comment: Also, thanks for the testcase, appreciate.

Comment: Really appreciate it! I haven't learned how to write the testcase yet.

Comment: @Woden They are really life-savers, much more than in other programming languages which do not have edge cases in several dimensions when calling a procedure. Just a begin_tests/end_tests block, and the clauses inside. The test assertions are meant to be in the head, but I prefer "assertion" calls in the body, the "code flow" moves with they eyes (i.e. you don't have to jump back to the head to see what is being tested). Run with `run_tests/0`.

Comment: @Woden It does seem to work. 1 solution found.

Comment: Thank you so much for the explanation and the code provided to explain what happened. I'll study it.

Comment: Just test it out! I think it's better to write the predicate separately instead of the nested one. It's clearer and easy to write. Thanks again and hope you all have a nice day.